# Restriction of complete 1-forms to closed submanifolds (Sharpe's book on Cartan geometries)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, cartan-geometry

In his Book *Differential Geometry: Cartan's generalization of Klein's Erlangen Program*, Sharpe gives the following definition of a **complete** 1-form:

[image: Definition 1.8.3 in Sharpe's book]

Soon thereafter he gives the following example:

[image: Example 1.8.5 in Sharpe's book]

I don't understand how to conclude this from the definition. Actually, I think I have found a counterexample: Consider $M = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $N = \mathbb{R} \times \{ 0 \}$ with
$$
    \omega = \begin{pmatrix}
        \cos y \frac{dx}{1 + x^2} \\
        \sin y \frac{dx}{1 + x^2} \\
        dy
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
A vector field $X$ on $M$ can only be constant if $\omega(X) \in \mathbf{e}_3 \cdot \mathbb{R}$, so it must be of the form $c \partial_y$ with $c$ constant. These vector fields are complete, so $\omega$ is complete. On the other hand,
$
\omega|_N = \mathbf{e}_1 \frac{dx}{1 + x^2} 
$
so $(1 + x^2) \partial_x$ is $\omega|_N$-constant. But the flow of this vector field is $\phi(t) = \tan t$ which is only defined up to time $ \frac{\pi}{2} $.

Is this counterexample correct? Did I misunderstand the author? Is there some way to "fix" this result?

Comment: You are correct. Sharpe is wrong.

Comment: The book Cap, Slovak, Parabolic Geometries I, might be a better source to learn about Cartan geometries, or at least a helpful supplement to Sharpe's book.

Comment: Yeaton Clifton's paper Completeness of Cartan connections is a nice source of interesting examples relevant to the story that Sharpe is telling.

Comment: You might also take a look at https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.14457